# can't run project on android studio

Tags: android-studio

I've never used android studio before and now I need to run this project on it:
https://github.com/madoe21/android-m3u-audio-video-streaming-player
[image]

I can't add configuration because there is no module

[image]

This is the "modules" page.
[image]

and I can't see anything about Gradle sync.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the project is very old that doesn't run create a new project and shirt the Java into a new project from the old project then the project run.

[see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncr5D.png)

Comment: good idea but so many errors occured

Comment: share the details of errors

Comment: for example cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

Comment: @wittream which android studio version you are currently using?

Comment: 2022.2 but I don't need this program anymore thank you very much for your help.